# Cant see my created array object's properties from main class

Tags: java, arrays

**class block**

```
public class block {    
public enum size {SMALL,MEDIUM,LARGE,XLARGE}
    public String color;public size sz;

public block(String color, size sz) {
    super();
    this.color = color;
    this.sz = sz;
}
     public block() {
    this.color="White";
    this.sz=sz.SMALL;

}

public String toString() {
    String result="My color is " + color + " and size=" + sz;
    return result;}
```

**Class rowOfBlock**

```
public class rowofBlocks extends block{

        private block[] blocks;
private int numofBlocks;

public rowofBlocks(int numofBlocks){
    //super();
    this.numofBlocks=numofBlocks;
    generateBlocks() ;
}

private void generateBlocks() {

    this.blocks=new block[numofBlocks];

}

public String toString() {
    for(int a=0;a<blocks.length;a++)
    {

    System.out.print( blocks[a]);
    }
    String a="d";
    return a;
}
}
```

**class gameMain**

```
public class gameMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {



block b=new block();
b.setSz(block.size.LARGE);
b.setColor("WHITE");

    rowofBlocks myrows=new rowofBlocks(3);
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(myrows);
    }}
```

What i mean is i just see nullnullnulld instead of My color is White when i try to create array of blocks.

Comment: Try to reduce the mass of code you post, focus on the relevant parts so you'll have a better chance to receive help and suggestions.

Comment: On an unrelated note, class names should start with a capital letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `null` values because you don't create any objects of class `Block` in your array in `RowOfBlocks`.

After creating the array with:

```
this.blocks = new block[numofBlocks];
```

in the method body of `generateBlocks()`

You have to iterate over it and insert actual blocks:

```
for(int i=0 ; i < this.blocks.length ; i++) {
     this.blocks[i] = new Block();
}
```

Comment: @user1418230 You're welcome. Next time try to post your question more clearly. Your code required a lot of formatting, some of which I did (but it's still not right when it comes to indentation). Also, you didn't include a tag for the programming language you used (it was edited in after you posted the question). Pay more attention to these things and your questions will not get downvoted so much. It will also be easier for you to get the right answers. Have a good day.